# ASP.NET Core MVC problem using Startup class from separate assembly

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I created a .NET Core MVC web app. I moved the Startup class to a separate library project that and added the dependency from the MVC project on the library project. In a third command line application I can use this Startup class. After I update the MVC project to use the Startup class in the library project instead of the default Startup class in the web project, the web server in Visual Studio gives me 404.

This localhost page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44323/
HTTP ERROR 404

I can debug the process through the end of this block in Startup.ConfigureServices(), but then the debugger just stops (no exception) and the browser shows the 404 page. The breakpoint in my action never triggers.

```cs
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});
```

Here is the Startup class. This is basically copied directly from the Visual Studio template with the addition of the DoWebStuff property, the CustomerServiceCollectionExtensions and DeliverystackServiceCollectionExtensions ConfigureContentstackRepository() calls, and the catchall route (I am just testing).

```cs
namespace Customer.Core.Configuration
{
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

    using Deliverystack.Contentstack.Core.Configuration;

    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            if (DoWebStuff)
            {
                services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
                {
                    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
                });

                // Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AddMvc(services).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
                services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            }

            // IMPORTANT: First configure deserialization from JSON. 
            CustomerServiceCollectionExtensions.ConfigureSerialization(services, Configuration);

            // then Add ContenstackOptions (connection details), ContentstackClient, and IRepository. 
            DeliverystackServiceCollectionExtensions.ConfigureContentstackRepository(
                services,
                Configuration);
        }

        public bool DoWebStuff { get; set; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (DoWebStuff)
            {
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                }
                else
                {
                    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                    app.UseHsts();
                }

                app.UseHttpsRedirection();
                app.UseStaticFiles();
                app.UseCookiePolicy();

                app.UseMvc(routes =>
                {
                    routes.MapRoute(
                        "default",
                        "{*url}",
                        new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"});
                });

                //            app.UseMvc(routes =>
                //            {
                //                routes.MapRoute(
                //                    name: "default",
                //                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                //            });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I start the command line tool, that works with this Startup class:

```cs
namespace scratch
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal;

    using Deliverystack.Contentstack.Core.Models;
    using Deliverystack.Contentstack.Core.Repositories;
    using Deliverystack.Core.Repositories;

    using Contentstack.Core;
    using Contentstack.Core.Models;
    using Customer.Core.Configuration;
    using Customer.Core.Models.Entries.DemoPage;
    using Customer.Core.Models.Entries.DemoPage.DemoBlocks;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HostingEnvironment env = new HostingEnvironment();
            //TODO: env.ContentRootPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            //TODO: env.EnvironmentName = "Development";
            IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile(
                "appsettings.json",
                optional: false,
                reloadOnChange: true).Build();
            Startup startup = new Startup(configuration); // this is in another project/assembly
            startup.DoWebStuff = false; // can't add parameters to constructor
            ServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            startup.ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);

            using (var provider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider())
            {
```

Here is the Startup class that I try to share to both command line and we apps:

```cs
namespace Customer.Core.Configuration
{
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

    using Deliverystack.Contentstack.Core.Configuration;

    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            if (DoWebStuff)
            {
                services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
                {
                    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
                });

                // Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AddMvc(services).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
                services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            }

            // IMPORTANT: First configure deserialization from JSON. 
            CustomerServiceCollectionExtensions.ConfigureSerialization(services, Configuration);

            // then Add ContenstackOptions (connection details), ContentstackClient, and IRepository. 
            DeliverystackServiceCollectionExtensions.ConfigureContentstackRepository(
                services,
                Configuration);
        }

        public bool DoWebStuff { get; set; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (DoWebStuff)
            {
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                }
                else
                {
                    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                    app.UseHsts();
                }

                app.UseHttpsRedirection();
                app.UseStaticFiles();
                app.UseCookiePolicy();

                app.UseMvc(routes =>
                {
                    routes.MapRoute(
                        "default",
                        "{*url}",
                        new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"});
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In an ASP.NET Core MVC app, is there any reason that I cannot use a Startup class from a separate library? Why does the debugger seem to crash? Why do I get 404 in this case? It seems like ASP.NET has crashed. Where might I look for logs?

Update 25.May.2020:

I may have a bit more information. I wrote a command script (.cmd file).

```
# C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.dotnet\tools\cs.cmd
# build and run cs project

cd <Solution Directory>
dotnet clean
cd <Web Project Directory>
dotnet run
```

http://localhost:5000 redirects to http://localhost 5001, browser shows ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR, click through to 404. Server shows:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[17]
      Connection id "0HM00F1LUUSI1" bad request data: "Invalid request line: '\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xFC\x03\x035\x8B\x83\xE8\xDBQ\xC7\xA0t67T\xA0\xF7\xEC\x8A\x9C\x8Df\xE5`\xF5\xD1g\x91\xE7\x00\xA9\x85\xD8u$ \xA9\xC3\x85\x9D \xF1>/)d\x1A{\x9AY\xC7F\xF58\xA38'0\xE3)\xE7z\x15\xD8\xDAcj\xA8\x00"\xEA\xEA\x13\x01\x13\x02\x13\x03\xC0+\xC0/\xC0,\xC00\xCC\xA9\xCC\xA8\xC0\x13\xC0\x14\x00\x9C\x00\x9D\x00/\x005\x00\x0A'"
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Invalid request line: '\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xFC\x03\x035\x8B\x83\xE8\xDBQ\xC7\xA0t67T\xA0\xF7\xEC\x8A\x9C\x8Df\xE5`\xF5\xD1g\x91\xE7\x00\xA9\x85\xD8u$ \xA9\xC3\x85\x9D \xF1>/)d\x1A{\x9AY\xC7F\xF58\xA38'0\xE3)\xE7z\x15\xD8\xDAcj\xA8\x00"\xEA\xEA\x13\x01\x13\x02\x13\x03\xC0+\xC0/\xC0,\xC00\xCC\xA9\xCC\xA8\xC0\x13\xC0\x14\x00\x9C\x00\x9D\x00/\x005\x00\x0A'
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.RejectRequestLine(Byte* requestLine, Int32 length)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.GetUnknownMethod(Byte* data, Int32 length, Int32& methodLength)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.ParseRequestLine(TRequestHandler handler, Byte* data, Int32 length)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.ParseRequestLine(TRequestHandler handler, ReadOnlySequence`1& buffer, SequencePosition& consumed, SequencePosition& examined)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.IHttpParser<TRequestHandler>.ParseRequestLine(TRequestHandler handler, ReadOnlySequence`1& buffer, SequencePosition& consumed, SequencePosition& examined)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.TakeStartLine(ReadOnlySequence`1 buffer, SequencePosition& consumed, SequencePosition& examined)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.ParseRequest(ReadOnlySequence`1 buffer, SequencePosition& consumed, SequencePosition& examined)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.TryParseRequest(ReadResult result, Boolean& endConnection)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

Debugging shows me that the contents of the IsDevelopment() block run.

If I comment app.UseHttpsRedirection():

```
dbug: HttpsConnectionAdapter[1]
      Failed to authenticate HTTPS connection.
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: An unknown error occurred while processing the certificate
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional()
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsServer(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsServerAsync>b__51_1(IAsyncResult iar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionAdapter.InnerOnConnectionAsync(ConnectionAdapterContext context)
dbug: HttpsConnectionAdapter[1]
      Failed to authenticate HTTPS connection.
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: An unknown error occurred while processing the certificate
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional()
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsServer(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsServerAsync>b__51_1(IAsyncResult iar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionAdapter.InnerOnConnectionAsync(ConnectionAdapterContext context)
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 28.3224ms 404
```

So I guess the question is, is this web server the same as that used by Visual Studio (in which case the cause is likely the same), and how do I disable this attempted SSL or other security stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55204707/asp-net-core-web-api-returns-404-when-startup-cs-in-different-assembly)

Comment: Thanks! It seems very similar, but that approach does not solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I never figured this out, but gave up, because I don't think that console and web projects should use the same Startup. The console project would need a bunch of dependencies that it should not just to disable web features otherwise enabled by startup. There must be a better way to manage any config/code shared to both.